# Add email address to sheet once Google form is submitted

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-forms, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a google form where the user can choose 1 of 5 options, "Red" "Green" "Blue" "Violet" "Yellow"
I want to be able to add an email address to a column when a form is submitted so that I can set up an easy mail merge.

For example 
David wanting 2 boxes from the blue team.

The "color -team" Name always comes in column "C". I want their group email to auto populate in Column "G" based on column >  C3 would be "Blue"
Then G3 would become "blueteam@gmail.com"

I am thinking this would be done with an array formula and the if-then sort of idea?

Any help or directions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Be more specific - You have a Google form, which lets you select 5 colors, and when the user submits the form, the answer appears in the sheet as color email address? Is it what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depends on how your form looks like if like this then use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A<>"", 
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B:F),,999^99)))&"team@gmail.com", ))
```

[image]

---

or perhaps:

```
={"emails"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", REGEXREPLACE(
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:F>0, B1:F1, )),,999^99)))&
 "team@gmail.com", "^team@gmail.com", ), ))}
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C3:C, {
 "Blue",   "BlueC_S-group@ucsc.edu";
 "Green",  "abc@gmail.com";
 "Yellow", "yellow@xxx.xx"}, 2, 0)))
```